# Bounded sequence in a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have a small question when we have a bouded sequence in a metric space; we say that there exists a closed ball $B'$ such that $(x_n)\subset B'$ or just there exist a ball $B$ such that $(x_n)\subset B$ ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Both definitions are equivalent. Note $$B_r(a) \subset \overline{B_r(x)} \subset B_{r+1}(x)$$

Comment: But in general it is a closed ball or any ball ?

Comment: While this shows that we *could* base everything on closed balls, we *usually* argue with open balls only - and be it to avoid that you accidentally use the closed ball of radius $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can proof that they are equivalent definitions.

Comment: Well, tampis just did it above.